# VBA - find max and min for each of two columns

Tags: vba, excel, indexing

I have two columns with data as double.
I'd like to create a vba script that does this:

Create a temporary third column that stores a lower value of each row.

Output min and max of the third column.

Now the problem is not to create this third column, I'd like this operation to be done in memory.

Please help
Thanks

Comment: show your attempt code

Comment: furthermore your question title (find max and min for each of two columns) doesn't match your narrative (Output min and max of each row lower values): please clarify

Comment: like `{=MIN(IF(A1:A6>B1:B6,B1:B6,A1:A6))&" - "&MAX(IF(A1:A6>B1:B6,B1:B6,A1:A6))}` would do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show a message box with minimum and a message box with maximum value, assuming the two columns are A and B.

```
Sub MinMax()

    ' Count the number of rows in the first column
    ' Assuming that number of rows in second column equals those in the first column
    HowFar = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

    ' Declare an array to store the minimums
    Dim Arr() As Double
    ReDim Arr(HowFar - 2)
    Dim Index As Integer
    Index = 0

    ' Loop through the first and second columns and store the minimums for each row in the array
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 2 To HowFar

        Minimum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("A" & i & ":B" & i))

        Arr(Index) = Minimum
        Index = Index + 1

    Next i

    ' Get the minimum value in the array
    Min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Arr)

    ' Get the maximum value in the array
    Max = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Arr)

    ' MsgBox the two values
    MsgBox ("Minimum = " & Min)
    MsgBox ("Maximum = " & Max)

End Sub
```